# Puppeteer: if duplicate, then x, else y

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

So I have this code which works great right now:

```
module.exports = async function grabResult(page) {
  const message = await page.$eval(
    'div > div:nth-child(2)',
    (el) => el.innerText
  );

  const username = await page.$eval(
    'child(15) .username',
    (el) => el.innerText
  );

  return { message, username };
};
```

The above code outputs:

```
{ message: 'message text', username: 'John' }
```

This code is runned on repeat and it grabs and outputs data multiple times a day.

What I'm trying to achieve is to output unique messages only and skip duplicates.

So, basically if the first time message is unique, output should be:

```
{ message: 'message text', username: 'John' }
```

If after some time it will try to grab the data again and will find that it still contains the same message, it should output an empty message:

```
{ message: '', username: 'John' }
```

I'm not a coder, but my logic is this:

1. Is it possible for Puppeteer to compare the last return with the new one?
   and do something accordingly?

or

2. Should I have three txt files:

txt1 - for freshly returned data

txt2 - for a unique message

txt3 - for non duplicated message.

So when a new message is returned it would add it to txt1.
Then it would compare txt1 with txt2.
If the messages are identical, it would add an empty message: `''` into txt3.

If txt1 and txt2 messages are different. Then it would add the freshly returned message to txt2 and txt3.

And repeat the process..

So basically txt3 will always have a unique message (or empty `''`).

Hope it's not too complicated.

As I mentioned, I'm not a coder. I guess there are way less complicated way to do that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Really need help with this one.

thanks.